# Have these graphs with a mindegree and weight condition been studied before?

Tags: graphs, reference-request

Consider a weighted undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ nodes. We call $G$ a *$(\tau,k,n)$-graph* if for every node $v \in V$ has at least $k$ neighbors and each edge has weight at least $\tau$.

Have these kind of graphs been studied in the literature in any context?

Comment: So something like a generalization of graphs with mindegree $k$?

Comment: @adrianN  I have updated the question. Sorry for the typos earlier.

Comment: Your edit made the question more confusing (for example, any edge is connecting precisely two vertices). I hopefully captured what you meant with my edit. Feel free to further edit or rollback if not.

Comment: @D.W. Last I checked, graph theory was a computer science topic.